# use anonymous function change work_mem failed

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

```
show is_superuser
```

The result is ON. Which means now my user/role is admin and it's a superuser.
execute the following code based on the attached tutorial:

```
Do $_$
Declare r record;
BEGIN
    FOR r in select u.rolname
        from pg_authid U
    join pg_auth_members m on m.member = u.OID
    join pg_authid g on g.oid = m.roleid
    where g.rolname = 'admin'
loop
    execute $$ alter role $$ || r.rolename || $$ set work_mem = '128MB' $$;
end loop;
end $_$;
```

then execute the following code:

```
select u.rolname, s.setconfig as setting
from pg_db_role_setting s
    join pg_authid u on u.oid = s.setrole
    join pg_auth_members m on m.member = u.oid
    join pg_authid g on g.oid = m.roleid
where g.rolname = 'admin';
```

my results show zero rows,
then I try to use `show work_mem`, the result is still 4MB. In this way, I believe it show appear 128MB, As per this two slides.
slide link: http://joeconway.com/presentations/fun_with_functions-PGConf.US-2015.pdf
[image: Tutroial]

Answer (score 1):

The role `admin` is a custom role, so you would have to [create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) it first and add users to it.

```sql
create role admin;
grant admin to myUserName;
```

This role is not related to the fact that you are a superuser.